# How can we track the message status ( like queued,sent,delivered etc ) using twilio studio workflow

Tags: twilio

I was using Twilio's sms api to send sms and i was able to track the delivery status using status call back url.But currently am planning to switch my implementation to twilio studio workflow but i didn't find a status call back functionality in it.

please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Studio send message widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-message) has two transitions, one for if the message was sent successfully and one if the message failed to send. It's not quite as nuanced as the statuses you can get callbacks for, but that is what is available. The [send and wait for reply widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-wait-reply) also has a transition for delivery failed.

Are these enough for your application?